# Solr indixing large content website

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I am using Solr 5.2 , I have a website with large content (bilingual), that needs to be indexed for search functionality, I need to index some meta data about each content (category, title, date,..), and I also need to index the content of the webpage, based on your knowledge and experience, is it correct to copy all the fields in a single field, and use this field for search, I am doing the following now

```
<fieldType name="compound_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ar.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>   
</fieldType>
<field name="compound_text_field" type="compound_text" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="author_name"         type="strings"  indexed="false" stored="false"/>
<field name="category"            type="strings"  indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="content_ar"            type="strings"  indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="content_en"            type="strings"  indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="content_title"       type="compound_text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="publish_date" type="tdate"/>
<copyField source="content_ar" dest="compound_text_field"/>
<copyField source="content_en" dest="compound_text_field"/>
<copyField source="content_title" dest="compound_text_field"/>
<copyField source="source" dest="compound_text_field"/>
<copyField source="category" dest="compound_text_field"/>
<copyField source="author_name" dest="compound_text_field"/>  
<fieldType name="text_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<field name="text_suggest_field" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="content_title" dest="text_suggest_field>
```

Comment: If you are using multi language better to have different index for each language or different fields for different language in one index.  here you are copying content_en(english field) to single field which has arabicfilterfactory.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to do so.. See whats suits your application...

1. Add new field in conf/schema.xml which acts like concatenation of all the fields you wanna search on.. Set that field as the defaultSearchField in the xml file and then send query without field name. You can use copyField to copy values to concatenated field.
2. You can use different query strings, then include them as "field:query" pairs separated by spaces.

It totally depends on the use case.

Comment: number 1 is exactly the approach i took, see compound_text_field in my schema, but is it correct to add arabic content and english content to the same field?